# Start Call transaction always fails on fresh installation, Callkit iOS

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit

I am using callkit for voip app, On Every Fresh install, CallKit startCallAction request fails and throws "com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction error 7".

Please find the method responsible below.

```
func performStartCallAction(handle: String) {
    let uuid = UUID()
    let callHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)
    let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction(call: uuid, handle: callHandle)
    let startCallTransaction = CXTransaction(action: startCallAction)
    callKitController.request(startCallTransaction) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("StartCallAction transaction request failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
        callUpdate.remoteHandle = callHandle
        callUpdate.supportsDTMF = true
        callUpdate.supportsHolding = true
        callUpdate.supportsGrouping = false
        callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = false
        callUpdate.hasVideo = false
        self.callKitProvider.reportCall(with: uuid, updated: callUpdate)
    }
}
```

**On Subsequent runs, the same code works fine.**

I am not sure What am I Doing Wrong, Please Help. TIA.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me as well. I can't find any solutions to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this - **initialize the CXProvider at the very start of the application's lifecycle**.

I had the same issue with the *`com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction error 7`* on a fresh install when attempting to use CallKit for initiating call transactions in iOS. The root cause of this problem was related to the timing of the CXProvider initialization.

**Bonus**: Remember that it's CXProvider must be a singleton in your application. ‍♂️